# Exclude lines that have duplicate words between delimiters

Tags: grep, scp

I have a folder structure that has been (badly) maintained by a number of automated jobs. One of the side effects of these jobs appear to be that it creates duplicate folder names (and subsequently duplicate images).

I have around 50GB worth of images hosted on this server and a conservative estimate suggests that at least 10% of this is duplicated. I'm in the process of migrating to some new infrastructure and would like to deduplicate the files and folders.

Given a directory structure as follow

```
images/New_Site/Food
images/New_Site/Food/Content
images/New_Site/Food/Content/Content
images/New_Site/Food/Content/Waterfall
images/New_Site/Food/Food
images/New_Site/Food/Food/Content
images/New_Site/Food/Food/Recipes
images/New_Site/Food/Recipes
images/New_Site/Food/Recipes/Recipes
images/New_Site/Home
images/New_Site/Home/Home
images/New_Site/Kids
images/New_Site/Kids/Kids
images/New_Site/Men
images/New_Site/Men/Men
images/New_Site/New_Site
images/New_Site/New_Site/Baby
images/New_Site/New_Site/Beauty
images/New_Site/New_Site/Corporate
images/New_Site/New_Site/Corporate/About
images/New_Site/New_Site/Corporate/Careers
images/New_Site/New_Site/Corporate/Education
images/New_Site/New_Site/Corporate/Legal
images/New_Site/New_Site/Food
```

I want to generate a script that would only copy the following folders (no recursion)

```
images/New_Site/Food
images/New_Site/Food/Content
images/New_Site/Food/Content/Waterfall
images/New_Site/Food/Recipes
images/New_Site/Home
images/New_Site/Kids
images/New_Site/Men
```

There are over 2200 folders in the current duplicated structure so manually cleaning it up is not an efficient repeatable process.

To complicate matters I need to migrate the deduplicated items from a AIX onto a Windows 2012 R2 environment. I can use Putty SCP to copy files between servers or I can create a zip archive (though at 50Gb, not sure if the Archive is a good idea).

My approach would be to find all folders, remove any folder that has a duplicate name immediately after the previous name using the '/' as a delimiter. So logically I can work it out but am unable to translate that into a grep command of some sort. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: So essentially, you want us to filter out the the buggy code you made? Why not just fix your code to generate the correct list of directories and use that?

Comment: Cool comment, but no. I'm trying to move away from the buggy code system to a new clean system. Also fixing the code won't make a difference to the existing 2200 plus folders that already reside on the file system.

Comment: Yes but if you separate out the directory generation part of your code you can more easily debug it. Then you can test it independently of the rest of your code and get it perfect. Doing that will also give you the list you're looking for (unless you are also planning to change the new dir structure).

Comment: I'd say that you have way more than 10% duplication here as well. By my count, using the logic you are asking for, 17 of these 24 lines should be removed, or 70%.

Comment: I simply took a sample of the directory listing that I thought would be representative of the problem that I'm facing. It shouldn't be seen as a statistical indication of the distribution of the duplication over the 2200 folders with which I have an issue.

Comment: As far as separating the directory generation from the problem, For the sake of this exercise lets assume it is no longer functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't grep but here is a bash script which should give you what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

srcdir=$1
destdir=$2
subdir=${3:-$destdir}
depth=$((${4:-0} + 1))
srcdirbase=${srcdir##*/}

for subdirdir in $srcdir/*/
do
   fixdir=${subdirdir%*/}
    fixbase=${fixdir##*/}
    if [ "$fixbase" != "*" -a "$fixbase" != "$srcdirbase" ]; then
        newsubdir=$subdir/$fixbase
        echo -e "mkdir \"$newsubdir\" && cp \"$fixdir/*\" \"$newsubdir\""
        if [ $depth -lt 20 ]; then
            ./$0 "$fixdir" "$destdir" "$newsubdir" $depth
        fi
    fi
done
```

If you name it `snowflake.sh` then you can call it like so:

```
 (echo "#\!$SHELL"; ./snowflake.sh <source_dir> <dest_dir>) > bugfix.sh
```

Replacing `<source_dir>` and `<dest_dir>` with the actual paths you have.

Comment: Thanks. Was staring blind at a grep solution, not thinking there might be other simple ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

How about  using this:

```
grep --invert-match '/(.+)/\1'
```

Or to match your modified test case

```
grep --invert-match '(.+)/\1'
```

Comment: I understand the theory behind this but having tried it, it doesn't seem to filter anything. Also it won't apply for a situation like `images/images/Food` with no leading `/`

Comment: @radimpe Are you sure it does not work? I don't have access to a Linux box right now but when I tried it on an online grep emulator it did work. http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp

Comment: @radimpe To address your new use case, why not just use a variant of the above 'grep --invert-match (.+)/\1'

Comment: @radimpe Perhaps I see why. You need extra single quotes to escape the regex from the shell's parser. See my modification now. I took that for granted since I always do that on the command line but got off guard since I was using an emulator right now so the quoting was superfluous. :)